# Console Cable via VGA->Mini Displayport adapter

Tags: mini-displayport, display-adapter

I can't seem to find an answer to this online as google keeps giving me VGA/Mini DP instead of console :(

Will a console cable work if it goes through a minis displayport adapter?

I can't test it until I need to use it due to the location of the WAP.

Really sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: What kind of console cable are you looking for?

Comment: @Hennes I have a RJ45 -> VGA just need to know if it will work with the adapter as my 15" MBPro doesn't have a VGA port

Comment: RJ45 as in 8P8C for cisco consoles? And VGA with three rows of contacts or 9 pins serial? (which looks like VGA but if quite different and found on many console cables).

Comment: @Hennes 9pin serial and forgive me but all I know is it looks like an RJ45 at the end :( (currently studying for my CCNA so will no doubt in time become less of a user on this stuff)

Comment: @Hennes just realised as the VGA and 9pin won't line up, and thus the adapter won't work :( so you've answered my question. next Q will be how do I get around this :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have an old style Ciso console cable. These are serial to serial. No VGA, Mini DP or USB is involved.

On one side the connector look like an RJ45 Ethhernet plug, but the network people always told me to call this 8P8C. It is a serial connector. On the other side you have a classic 9 pins connector.

If I am right it looks like this:
[image: Cisco cable]

To connect it you need a serial port. These were very common on old boards, but these days they have mostly been replaced by USB. This leaves you with two options:

1. But a USB to serial convertor. These are cheap (starting at €10) and often usefull.
2. Find a motherboard with a serial connector. I assumed that these mostly died out but to my surprise I still found serial headers on my recent Z170 Skylake board.

Option 1 is probably the easiest.

Comment: Awesome thanks, was about to say to put it as an answer so I could give you some points :)